# Scroll bar in LibreOffice dialog

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

I am trying to make an image picker component in LibreOffice.
I have a dialog that is dynamically filled with images. When the user clicks on one images, it should be selected and the dialog should be closed.
The problem is that the number of images is variable. So I need to enable scrolling in the dialog (so that the user can navigate through all images).

There seems to be some properties on the dialog object (Scrollbars, Scroll width, Scroll height, etc)
However, I cannot find a way to use them anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: > "There seems to be some properties on the dialog object"
Where you find those properties? Looking into it I don't find any in the Basic Dialog Editor or the API documentation.
Maybe you confuse it with properties of a Form?

Comment: @ngulam I am not sure why you cannot see it. I can see these in the dialog editor. I am using LO 5.0.0.5 (x64)

Comment: My bad - looked at the wrong version.  LO has it in version 4.3 and 5.0.0.5, sorry for disturbance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrollbar is one of the `Controls` available through the dialog box editor.  That is the easier way to put a `ScrollBar` on a dialog box.  Just insert it like any other control.  There is a harder way via `DialogModel.addControl` but that seems non-essential to answering this question.

If you add a scrollbar to the dialog box and run the dialog box, you will find it does nothing by default.  The functionality (apparently) must be written into a macro.  The appropriate triggering event is the `While Adjusting` event on the `ScrollBar` object, although it does not trigger the macro simply with the "Test Mode" function in the dialog editor.  Running the dialog box through a macro triggers the `While Adjusting` event when the scroll arrows are triggered, when the slider area is clicked to move the slider, and when the slider itself is dragged.  The `Object` variable returned by the scrollbar event contains a property `.Value` which is an absolute value between 0 and the `EventObject.Model.ScrollValueMax`, which allows you to manipulate the other objects on the page manually based on the position of the slider.

Yes, that's right, manipulate objects manually.  The sole example I found, from the [LibreOffice 4.5 SDK](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/BasicAndDialogs/ToolkitControls/ToolkitControls/ScrollBar.xba), does precisely this.  Of course, it is not as bad as it sounds, because one can iterate through all of the objects on the page by reading the array `Dialog.getControls()`.  In any event, the secret sauce of the example provided in the SDK is to define `Static` variables to save the initial positions of all of the objects you manipulate with the scrollbar and then simply index those initial positions based on a ratio derived from the scrollbar `Value` divided by the `ScrollValueMax`.

Here is a very simple working example of how to scroll.  This requires a saved `Dialog1` in the `Standard` library of your document, which contains an object `ScrollBar1` (a vertical scrollbar) and `Label1` anywhere in the dialog.  The `ScrollBar1` must be configured to execute the macro `ScrBar` subroutine (below) on the `While Adjusting` event.  Open the dialog by executing the `OpenDialog` macro and the scrollbar will move the `Label1` control up and down in proportion to the page.

```
Sub OpenDialog

   DialogLibraries.LoadLibrary("Standard")
   oVariable = DialogLibraries.Standard.Dialog1
   oDialog1 = CreateUnoDialog( oVariable )
   oDialog1.Execute()

End Sub

Sub ScrBar (oEventObj As Object)
  Static bInit As Boolean
  Static PositionLbl1Y0 As Long

  oSrc = oEventObj.Source
  oSrcModel = oSrc.Model

  scrollRatio = oEventObj.Value / oSrcModel.ScrollValueMax

  oContx = oSrc.Context
  oContxModl = oContx.Model

  oLbl1 = oContx.getControl("Label1")
  oLbl1Model = oLbl1.Model

  REM on initialization remember the position of the label
  If bInit = False Then
     bInit = True
     PositionLbl1Y0 = oLbl1Model.PositionY
  End If    

  oLbl1Model.PositionY  = PositionLbl1Y0 - (scrollRatio * oContx.Size.Height)

End Sub
```

The example provided by the SDK does not run on my setup, but the principles are sound.

There appears to be a second improvised method closer to the functionality one might expect.  This method uses the `DialogModel.scrollTop` property.  The property appears to iterate the entire box up or down as a scroll based on the user input.  There are two problems using this methodology, however.  First, unless you put the scrollbar somewhere else, the scroll bar will scroll away along with the rest of the page.  You will need to adjust the location of the scrollbar precisely to compensate for/negate the scrolling of the entire page.  In the example below I tried but did not perfect this.  Second, the property seems to miss inputs with frequency and easily goes out of alignment/ enters a maladjusted state.  Perhaps you can overcome these limitations.  Here is the example, relying on the same setup described above.

```
Sub ScrBar (oEventObj As Object)
  Static scrollPos
  oSrc = oEventObj.Source
  oSrcModel = oSrc.Model

  scrollRatio = oEventObj.Value / oSrcModel.ScrollValueMax
  If IsEmpty(scrollPos) = False Then 
    scrollDiff = oEventObj.Value - scrollPos
  Else
    scrollDiff = oEventObj.Value
  End If
  scrollPos = oEventObj.Value

  oContx = oSrc.Context
  oContxModl = oContx.Model

  oContxModl.scrollTop = scrollDiff * -1
  oSrcModel.PositionY=(scrollRatio * oContx.Size.Height/5) * -1 
End Sub
```

This (sort of) will scroll the contents of the entire dialog box, within limits and with the caveats noted above.